# Ordinary generating functions and Stieltjes-Perron Inversion Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, generating-functions

I am reading the appendix of a paper where they take ordinary generating functions $g(x)=\sum_{n\geq0} a_nx^n$ and use the Stieltjes Perron inversion theorem to determine the weight (density) function such that the sequence $a_n$ are the moments of orthogonal polynomials.

The steps are to:

1. find $G(z)=\frac{1}{z}g(\frac{1}{z})=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{a_n}{z^{n+1}}$
2. plug in $z=x+iy$, where $x+iy$ is a complex number in standard form
3. find the imaginary part of $G(x+iy)$, call it $Im(G(x+iy))$
4. determine what is $-\frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{y\rightarrow0^+}Im(G(x+iy))$

The result should be the density function we desire.

The author provides an example, which I will put below and [link](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL21/Barry/barry362.pdf) here (page 36, Appendix).

Let $g(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$, the Catalan generating function.

Then, $G(z)=\frac{1}{z}g(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{z-4}{z}}\right)$.

This next step is where I am lost on how the author got this and would love a walkthrough of how to determine the imaginary part of $G(x+iy)$. The author states

$Im(G(x+iy))=-\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2-8x+y^2-16}-x^2+4x-y^2}}{4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

I have been trying to fill in the details of how he got this generating function, but to no avail. I'm assuming there is a simple algebraic trick that I am missing to get $i$ from under the square root. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean $a_n$ rather than $a^n$ at the beginning?

Comment: Looks like you rationalize the denominator, so you get $$\frac{z-4}{z}=\frac{z\overline z-4\overline z}{z\overline z}=\frac{x^2+y^2-4x+4iy}{x^2+y^2}$$ Then you need a formula for the square root of $u+vi$ where $u=x^2+y^2-4x, v=4y.$

Comment: It's certainly not a fun exercise, but it is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking. I was able to figure it out from there. Yes, it should be a_n, I’ll fix it lol.